# Uniform upper bound related to unidimensional symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider the following basic random walk : $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where the $(X_k)$
are i.i.d. with $P(X_k=(-1))=P(X_k=1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Let $M_n=\max(0,S_1,S_2, \ldots ,S_n)$ and $\mu(n,t)=P(M_n \leq t)$.

Using the reflection principle , (as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234/random-walk-0)), and putting 
$q=\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$ one can see that

$$
\mu(n,t)=P\bigg( -2\lfloor \frac{t}{2} \rfloor-1\leq S_{2q+1} \leq 2\lceil \frac{t}{2} \rceil-1\bigg)=\frac{1}{2^{2q+1}} \sum_{j=-\lfloor \frac{t}{2} \rfloor}^{\lceil \frac{t}{2} \rceil} \binom{2q+1}{q+j} \tag{1}
$$

The Stirling formula yields $\binom{2q+1}{q+j} \sim_{q \to \infty} \frac{2^{2q+1}}{\sqrt{\pi q}}$ for any $j$, and hence for a fixed $t$,

$$
\mu(n,t) \sim_{n\to \infty} (t+1) \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}} \tag{2}
$$

I ask if this limit is also an uniform upper bound, in the sense that

$$
\mu(n,t) \leq (t+1) \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}} \text{ whenever }
\ \mu(n,t) \ \text{is not trivial (i.e. equal to } 0 \ \text{ or } \ 1).
\tag{3}
$$

**UPDATE 02/14/2013**  I’ve just realized that the two-variables inequality
(3) follows from the much simpler one-variable inequality

$$
\frac{\binom{2q+1}{q}}{2^{2q+1}} \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi (q+1)}} \tag{4}
$$

Indeed, the numerator in the RHS of (1) is a sum of $t+1$ binomials, and the largest such binomial is $\binom{2q+1}{q}$. So (1) implies that

$$
\mu(n,t) \leq (t+1) \frac{\binom{2q+1}{q}}{2^{2q+1}} \tag{5}
$$

Inequality (4) looks much easier to prove.

Comment: I changed {\sf max} to \max.  That is standard usage and has the effect of providing proper spacing before and after $\max$ in things like $a\max b$, and also, in "displayed" contexts, of suitably positioning subscripts, thus: $\displaystyle\max_{x\in S} f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES, and indeed inequality (4) is true. To see this, put

$$
u_q=\frac{\binom{2q+1}{q}}{2^{2q+1}}\sqrt{q+1} \tag{5}
$$

Then the usual Stirling formula stuff shows that $u_q \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. To show
(4), it will therefore suffice to show that $(u_q)$ is increasing. So let us
compute $\frac{u_{q+1}}{u_q}$. Using

$$
\binom{2q+3}{2q+1}=\frac{2(2q+3)}{q+2} \binom{2q+1}{q},
$$

we obtain

$$
\frac{u_{q+1}}{u_q} =\frac{q+\frac{3}{2}}{\sqrt{(q+1)(q+2)}},
$$

and this is $\gt 1$ by the AM-GM inequality, qed.