# What random process is this?

Tags: random-walk

This is a rather basic question, is just that I don't know a thing about this subject. Let's say $x$ is an integer. At $t=0$, the value of $x$ is 1. Then, at each time step, one of the following happens:

- $x$ goes to $x+1$, with probability $p_1 < \frac{1}{2}$
- $x$ remains with the same value with probability $ 1 - 2 p_1 $
- $x$ goes to $x-1$, with probability $p_1 < \frac{1}{2}$

I'm interested in knowing the distribution of the time $t^*$ when $x$ reaches the value zero for first time.

Comment: Are you familiar with the answer if p_1 = 1/2?

Comment: @John That would be [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk), but even in this article I don't see anything about $t^*$. How can I connect both however?

Comment: How accurate an answer do you need?

Comment: @John I would rather like some pointers. For example, what results are out there if we say $p_1 = 1/2 $ ?

Comment: This is covered by my very first answer in MSE. Equation ($\ast$) gives you
the distribution for the hitting time of state "1" starting at "0", but 
this is the same as hitting time of state "0" starting at "1". In the
line following ($\ast$) I assume that $p_1=1/2$, but not before.    
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234/random-walk-0/4235#4235

Comment: See also http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/monthly753-756-hofstad.pdf

Comment: Thanks @ByronSchmuland, this will get me started.

Comment: @dsign Glad to help!