# Survival probability of 1D Random Walker

Tags: random-walk

For a 1 D random walk on $Z$ axis, starting at $z=0$, equal probability to go to right or left, what is the probability that during the first k steps the walker's position remains $z\leq m$?

This is also called the survival probability. I can write is as a sum of first passage time probabilities, but I am looking for a closed form.

Thanks,

Comment: I meant during the first k steps the position should be at m or lower. (I edited the question). Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You can always use the reflection principle to get an explicit expression as in my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234/random-walk-0/4235#4235 I don't think you will get a simpler closed form than this.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Wow, a question and answer with a four-digit number from $2010$ -- early math.SE history :-) Actually this is a duplicate of that question, no?

Comment: @joriki It was my first answer on MSE. Ancient history!

Comment: Byron, Thank for that. I saw your answer there. You mean we don't have a closed for for the CDF of the occupancy probability? $P(0\leq Xt<|b|)$

Comment: @ByronSchmuland hank for that. I saw your answer there. You mean we don't have a closed for for the CDF of the occupancy probability? P(0≤Xt<|b|)