# Question about stopped martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Suppose $T$ is a a stopping time and $X$ is a martingale. We know that this means the stopped martingale $X_{T \wedge n}$ is also a martingale.

Furthermore this means that: $$E[X_{T \wedge n}] = E[X_{0}] $$ for all $n$.

My question is: is there e a difference between $T$ being finite i.e $Pr (T< \infty)$$=1$ and $T$ being bounded above i.e $T$ ($ω$)$ < c$ for any $ω \in\Omega$ in context of this equality: 
$$E[X_{T}] = E[X_{0}] $$

If so, can you provide some intuition/examples?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402280/stopping-theorem-counterexample

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you!